# How to apply ellipsis to the actual spinner instead of the dropdown views?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How do I apply an ellipsis to the spinner instead of the dropdown views? When I search for terms like `spinner custom view`, `spinner ellipsis` or `spinner long text` I get results for the views in the dropdown.
For example:

- [Spinner with long text not working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720665/spinner-with-long-text-not-working-fine)
- [How to wrap lengthy text in a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107500/how-to-wrap-lengthy-text-in-a-spinner)
- [Spinner does not wrap text -- is this an Android bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139106/spinner-does-not-wrap-text-is-this-an-android-bug)
- [I have Spinner with some items, some of which have long text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009398/i-have-spinner-with-some-items-some-of-which-have-long-text)

This is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for the actual spinner text.

An image to illustrate my problem

[image]

The content is `Recipe for disaster/Freeing king awowogei` but the spinner tries to place it on the next line, which is what I do not want. Instead it should add ellipsis at the end and displaying `Recipe for disaster/Freeing king awo...` or something.

The spinner content is loaded from a string array and a custom adapter, this all works fine.

I've tried adding

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
```

To my custom dropdown view, but that's not working. The spinner does not have properties regarding text wrapping so I cannot find out how to achieve this.

The container for the Spinner has a height of 50dp because I do not want the spinner to be higher than that.

And in case it's relevant the simplified xml code of the views

`quest_row.xml` the view that I use in my adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/input_background_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quest_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`quest.xml` the main layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/quest_selector_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `android:ellipsize="end"` on the `TextView` that you are using in your `SpinnerAdapter` (`quest_row.xml`, I assume).

Your question shows that you tried `android:ellipsize="marquee"`, which will not work and isn't what you are looking for anyway ("it should add ellipsis at the end").

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't seem to work. The text inside the spinner is still being wrapped to the next line, like in my image

Comment: Make sure that you are applying it to the right layout. Usually there are two separate layouts used with a `SpinnerAdapter`, one for the selected view when the `Spinner` is closed and one for the rows in the scrolling list when the `Spinner` is open.

Comment: Seems to do the trick! Had to override `getView` and `getDropDownView`